# performance optimization regarding double/float and passing parameters

Tags: c#

I replaced all doubles with floats in my project, which resulted in performance improvement.

All my functions now, take arguments not as references. If I pass them as references I would save one copy. As you know, parameters if not passed as reference, are copied in the function.

I was wondering if that is worth it doing for like 200 functions, and should I expect improvements?

Thank you

Comment: By replacing `doubles` with `floats` you've made your project potentially less accurate. Is this acceptable? You must always *think* about your changes and the effect that they will have. It's not always worth doing these things.

Comment: wihtout any further details (like source code, how often are these called etc.) that is really hard to tell... so please provide some details like source code and which usage patterns are relevant to the performance aspects...

Comment: No. Any improvement would be negligible and until you know that you need it, you shouldn't microoptimize. You know that it's also possible that in converting from doubles to floats you've also changed the behavior of your program and, possibly, invalidated the results.  Floats have much less precision than doubles and if you need that precision in your program you may have just broken it.

Comment: Floats are fine, I don't need that much precision. I have tested all and it works fine. About how often, well lot of functions are called for like 80 ships each frame. That is a lot i guess.

Answer (score 1):

Generally no.

The golden rule:

> Premature optimization is the root of evil

First you find the bottleneck, the slowest part of your program, then you optimize it.
Then you find a new bottleneck and repeat.

And first, you start by optimizing the algorithm, then the data structures, then the data, then the code, and last the techniques.

Comment: The algorithms and data structures can't be optimized further

Comment: Then where is your bottleneck?

Comment: I just noticed I use Vector with three members, x,y,z. I used it here only for 2d stuff, I will remove one dimension and see if that brings improvement.

Comment: Changed that, eh not that much improvement. I can spawn 10 more ships.

Comment: If you cannot find a bottleneck by analyzing the code, use some kind of profiler to determine where the bottleneck is and then optimize it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the methods are called thousands of times in a second, I wouldn't change the behavior.

You know that passing stuff by reference can really mess up the logic behind your classes. Some things are not meant to be modified or changed unless you want to change them. (Use accessor methods to change your instance variables).

Otherwise it would be a call for [micro-optimization](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html) and it is absolutely not worth spending your time on modifying 200 methods just for small performance increases.

<strike>Objects</strike>Value types created inside a method are sitting on the stack - which means that they are purged once not needed anymore.

Comment: Yep they are called a lot each frame.

Comment: From what it sounds it seems like there are a lot of calculations going on. It might be beneficial if you worked with references. But as Guffa pointed out, depending on your architecture it could do more harm than help. 

But before changing all functions, I would suggest you to watch out for any other kind of performance bottlenecks such as big objects created multiple times when you only need one.

Comment: Objects are always on the heap, regardless of where they are created. Value types that are local variables in a method are on the stack, including variables that are references to objects.

Answer (score 1):

No, you won't get any performance benefit by passing a `float` by reference.

On a 32 bit system, the `float` is the same size as the pointer to it. On a 64 bit system the pointer is twice as big as the `float`.

Besides, even when the pointer is smaller than the value type, passing by reference means that the method needs to access the value by reference also, which outweights the performance gain of the smaller parameter type.